# rpc sendResponse panic:reflect: call of reflect.Value.Int on ptr

Tags: go, rpc, panic

My server is running well in the production environment when it panic'd the day before yesterday.

I posted an issue in the Go Forum and someone told me to do race detection.

I see net/rpc.(*Server).sendResponse is thread safe.

Is there anything wrong with sendResponse in rpc package？

In my code, reply is only a *int and doesn't do anything functionally so I have no idea with this panic:

```
panic: reflect: call of reflect.Value.Int on ptr Value [recovered]  
panic: reflect: call of reflect.Value.Int on ptr Value  
goroutine 52598456 [running]:  
encoding/gob.catchError(0xc4209e10d0) 
/root/go/src/encoding/gob/error.go:38 +0x95  
    panic(0xc40860, 0xc42606ad00) 
/root/go/src/runtime/panic.go:489 +0x2cf  
    reflect.Value.Int(0xbcdec0, 0xc4251fe520, 0x196, 0x196)  
/root/go/src/reflect/value.go:902 +0xb5  
    encoding/gob.encInt(0xc423ab4ae0, 0xc422da1e40, 0xbcdec0, 0xc4251fe520, 0x196)  
/root/go/src/encoding/gob/encode.go:188 +0x43  
    encoding/gob.(*Encoder).encodeStruct(0xc4209e1040, 0xc4209e1078, 0xc421a28a20, 0xcc1be0, 0xc4251fe510, 0x199)  
/root/go/src/encoding/gob/encode.go:334 +0x256  
    encoding/gob.(*Encoder).encode(0xc4209e1040, 0xc4209e1078, 0xcc1be0, 0xc4251fe510, 0x199, 0xc4209c3480)  
/root/go/src/encoding/gob/encode.go:707 +0x1d3
    encoding/gob.(*Encoder).EncodeValue(0xc4209e1040, 0xc95bc0, 0xc4251fe510, 0x16, 0x0, 0x0)  
/root/go/src/encoding/gob/encoder.go:250 +0x3ab  
    encoding/gob.(*Encoder).Encode(0xc4209e1040, 0xc95bc0, 0xc4251fe510, 0x0, 0x0) 
/root/go/src/encoding/gob/encoder.go:175 +0x61  
    net/rpc.(*gobServerCodec).WriteResponse(0xc422b51ec0, 0xc422d737d0, 0xc95bc0, 0xc4251fe510, 0xc422b43a40, 0xc422b4a350)  
/root/go/src/net/rpc/server.go:424 +0x1dd  
    net/rpc.(*Server).sendResponse(0xc420055680, 0xc422b45aa0, 0xc421c4ff00, 0xc95bc0, 0xc4251fe510, 0x1334ac0, 0xc422b51ec0, 0x0, 0x0)  
/root/go/src/net/rpc/server.go:366 +0x130  
    net/rpc.(*service).call(0xc422afe900, 0xc420055680, 0xc422b45aa0, 0xc422b4ec00, 0xc421c4ff00, 0xbc3800, 0xc427ab07e0, 0x16, 0xc95bc0, 0xc4251fe510, ...)  
/root/go/src/net/rpc/server.go:394 +0x22e  
    created by net/rpc.(*Server).ServeCodec  
/root/go/src/net/rpc/server.go:481 +0x404
```

---

`type RpcArgs struct{
    A string
    B int32
    C string
    D int32
    E String
    F int32 
    G int32
    H int32 
    I bool
    J string
    K int32
    L String
    M int32 
    N int32
    O int32 
    P bool
}`

`func RPC1(args *RpcArgs, reply *int) error{
    //some simple logic with args, do noting with reply
    //do another async rpc call,may be this is useless
    var reply2 int
    rpc.Client.Go(serviceMethod, args, &reply2, make(chan *rpc.Call, 1))
    return nil
}`

The source code just like that.reply *int is return directly which is not modified in RPC1

Comment: Run the race detector. Then try to check what data triggered this - perhaps you had unusual data which caused the panic? You'll probably  need to provide code at the point of error for someone to help. I'd try to reproduce it first.

Comment: @KennyGrant ,the code in this comment is not right format, so i post it below, thank you~

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is an issue with the `sendResponse` function in the `net/rpc` package.

The request panics in the Encode function when it comes across a pointer which is `nil`. You should read the documentation on `gob/encodeStruct` to see under what situations it fails to encode values.